# Selecting a drop-down element results in error : "Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape information off this [page](https://macmap.org/en//query/results?reporter=762&partner=004&product=850300&level=6) by selecting the available drop-down elements (in this case 3).
[drop-down image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s1pW.jpg)

But when I try this code:

```
dropdownEle <- remdr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = 
 paste('/html/body/section/div/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div/div/select/option[1]',sep = ''))
dropdownEle$clickElement()
```

I get error like this:

```
Selenium message:element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I tried giving the dynamic xpath like this:

```
(//select[@id='ntlc-product-list']/child::option)[1]
```

but even that is not working.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: There are no options to select from dropdown, as I can see when some text is entered few options are shown. So did u type something first and try to search

Comment: @ChandraShekhar i believe you are trying at the top part of the page. Refer the image I've uploaded. It is a drop-down and there are 3 elements inside it

Comment: Did u click on dropdown first ? and try to pick any options then

Comment: @ChandraShekhar yes i have. it does not recognize the clicks to any of the options.